# Hyper V network adapter for NAT and bridge

Tags: networking, vpn, hyper-v

I had a Ubuntu 18.04 guest on Virtual Box with below network settings
Guest Operating System: Ubuntu 10.04
Network Interface 1: NAT
Network Interface 2: Bridged with Wifi

I have VPN client only available on my host system. With NAT, the ubuntu guest could able to access systems via VPN. At the same time I could login to SSH on ubuntu guest from host.

The host machine is running Windows 10.

---

Now I am trying to do same setup on Microsoft Hyper-V GUI

Guest Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04

Networking, I could able to have only one adapter. I am not sure how to configure network to

1. Access VPN of Host OS systems from guest Ubuntu.
2. Access SSH of guest Ubuntu from Host Windows & Neighbors on same WI-FI

Thanks

Comment: You need a separate Wi-Fi adapter for the Ubuntu guest (USB Passthrough).

Comment: Hyper-V doesn’t do USB passthrough. I believe it also doesn’t do bridging to Wi-Fi (because that requires special tricks to “work”).

Comment: Maybe consider a different virtualizing app. I use VMware and it support passthrough.